# How separate php array with same value and not same

Tags: php, arrays

I have a shop basket with for example 6 items. Some items are for one shop and another items for one and maybe two shops.

I want create factors for each shops. How can I do? How can I known these items in basket are for one shop or has for 2 or 3 shop . How can separate this items to factor.

```
Array('customer' => Array('basket' => Array(
                    '9_2' => Array
                        (
                            "row" => "0",
                            'item' => 'cd',
                            'count' => '1',
                            'sale_start_date' => '1391-12-25 19:27:56',
                            'sale_end_date' => '1392-04-20 19:27:49',
                            'sale_price' => '40500',
                            'price' => '54564',
                            'id' => '999035',
                            'shopid' => '4'
                        ),
                        '999_17' => Array
                        (
                            'row' => '1',
                            'item' => 'car',
                            'count' => '1',
                            'sale_start_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_end_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_price' => '0',
                            'price' => '520000',
                            'id' => '999039',
                            'code' => 'b125nh',
                            'shopid' => '6'
                        ),
                        '9_3' => Array
                        (
                            'row' => '2',
                            'item' => 'book',
                            'count' => '1',
                            'sale_start_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_end_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_price' => '0',
                            'price' => '520000',
                            'id' => '999039',
                            'code' => 'b125nh',
                            'shopid' => '4'
                        ),
                        '10_5' => Array
                        (
                            'row' => '2',
                            'item' => 'dvd',
                            'count' => '1',
                            'sale_start_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_end_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_price' => '0',
                            'price' => '520000',
                            'id' => '999039',
                            'code' => 'b125nh',
                            'shopid' => '5'
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
```

This example is array from my SESSION . I want seperate factor with shopid value. In this basket for example we have 2 item from `shopid=4` and have 1 item from `shopid=6` and one item from `shopid=5` how can create seprate factor for each shop.

First I use usort function for sort array with shopid but I can't continue for separate each same and not same item shop for create factor

Comment: Why don't you use shop id as index in array? `['basket' => [4 => 'shop4 data', 5 => 'shop5 data']]`

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear to me. Do you want to have a multidimensional array where all the items are in a different array for each shop_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
<?php

$shopItems = array();
foreach ($_SESSION['customer']['basket'] as $basket) {
    $key = $basket['shopid'];
    $shopItems[$key][] = $basket;
}
```

This will store groups of items from the same shop id in elements of the array $shopItems

For example (only showing shop id 4)

```
Array (
    [4] => Array (
        [0] => array(
            "row" => "0",
            'item' => 'cd',
            'count' => '1',
            'sale_start_date' => '1391-12-25 19:27:56',
            'sale_end_date' => '1392-04-20 19:27:49',
            'sale_price' => '40500',
            'price' => '54564',
            'id' => '999035',
            'shopid' => '4'
        ),
        [1] => array(
            'row' => '2',
            'item' => 'book',
            'count' => '1',
            'sale_start_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            'sale_end_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            'sale_price' => '0',
            'price' => '520000',
            'id' => '999039',
            'code' => 'b125nh',
            'shopid' => '4'
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$basket = array();
foreach ($_SESSION['customer']['basket'] as $k => $v)
    $basket[$v['shopid']][$k] = $v;
print_r($basket);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [9_2] => Array
                (
                    [row] => 0
                    [item] => cd
                    [count] => 1
                    [sale_start_date] => 1391-12-25 19:27:56
                    [sale_end_date] => 1392-04-20 19:27:49
                    [sale_price] => 40500
                    [price] => 54564
                    [id] => 999035
                    [shopid] => 4
                )

            [9_3] => Array
                (
                    [row] => 2
                    [item] => book
                    [count] => 1
                    [sale_start_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [sale_end_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [sale_price] => 0
                    [price] => 520000
                    [id] => 999039
                    [code] => b125nh
                    [shopid] => 4
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [999_17] => Array
                (
                    [row] => 1
                    [item] => car
                    [count] => 1
                    [sale_start_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [sale_end_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [sale_price] => 0
                    [price] => 520000
                    [id] => 999039
                    [code] => b125nh
                    [shopid] => 6
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [10_5] => Array
                (
                    [row] => 2
                    [item] => dvd
                    [count] => 1
                    [sale_start_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [sale_end_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [sale_price] => 0
                    [price] => 520000
                    [id] => 999039
                    [code] => b125nh
                    [shopid] => 5
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
function get_seperated_shops($all_items)
{
    $seperated_shops = array();
    foreach($all_items AS $item => $properties)
    {
        $seperated_shops[$properties['shopid']][$item] = $properties;
    }
    return $seperated_shops;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(get_seperated_shops($_SESSION['customer']['basket']));
echo "</pre>";
```